# What are the memory/bandwidth implications of Parse pointers?

Tags: pointers, memory, parse-platform, limit

Parse mention that a column could contains an unlimited amount of pointers. I'm developing some cloud code to act as an API for Android and iOS and I was wondering what the memory implications were of sending thousands of pointers over the network.

Will they essentially be sent as integers, longs or strings when cloud code API is called? If I was retrieving a list of users with 1000 pointers attached to each one of them, is this going to have a huge impact on performance?

Is there a memory limitation which might truncate my pointers during a query?